# Failed to load a dll in the Temp Directory on a Windows Server

Tags: c#, windows, exception, dll, permissions

I have developed an C# application that run very well in local.

But there is a problem when i put on the server.

The application use a DLL library (A.dll) in a point of the execution, this A.dll copy (or is create at the first execution) another DLL (B.dll) in the AppData/Local/TEMP directory. But when the A.dll try to load the B.dll an exception is threw:

```
system.invalidoperationexception: failed to load B.dll
```

I have tried to run as Administrator the main exe, but with no results. And i think that the permissions are ok, after all is the TEMP directory.

I have not access at the DLLs source, are libraries.

Anyone can suggest me any solution? Would i check better? Where?

Thank You All.

Comment: You may want to try installing the DLL into the GAC, more info here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dkkx7f79.aspx

Comment: wich dll i will install?
The A.dll or the B.dll? Or both?
Another thing is that i will utilize the Frameworke net 4.0.
Gacutil is for the 4.5 there is a proble?

Comment: Why not put both dlls in the same directory as the .exe?

Comment: I think that the A.dll have in the code, to put/create/copy the B.dll in the temp path.
I already tried to put all togheter, with no results

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that the system does not restrict execution of code from within the temp directory, e.g. using SRP or AppLocker?

This is usually set in group policy and is generally a sensible restriction these days to prevent things such as drive-by installers and cryptolocker malware.

You can verify this by trying to run an executable from %TEMP% and seeing if you get an access denied error.

If this is the case you can try relocating TEMP (as SRP usually defaults to locking you out of %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp and moving the Temp folder will have the desired effect.

Hope this helps!